# DOMMatrix scaleSelf broken?

Tags: javascript, canvas, matrix-multiplication, path-2d

I don't know if anybody actually uses this, but I want to use the [DOMMatrix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMMatrix) object to position and **SCALE** an SVG-path on a HTMLCanvas 2d-context.

```js
var path = new Path2D("M0.55,0.55 C0.55,0.55,0.45,0.55,0.45,0.55 C0.45,0.55,0.45,0.45,0.45,0.45 C0.45,0.45,0.55,0.45,0.55,0.45 C0.55,0.45,0.55,0.55,0.55,0.55");

var matrix = new DOMMatrix();
matrix.translateSelf(50,50);
matrix.scaleSelf(5); // <-- THIS IS THE PROBLEM!

//add matrix to SVG-Path 
var draw = new Path2D();
draw.addPath(path, matrix);

ctx.strokeStyle = "lime";
ctx.stroke(draw);
```

Now, for some reason scaleSelf() destroys the matrix. The objects attributes get filled with NAN.

**Before scale**

[image: Before scale]

**After scale**

[image]

Anybody got a fix?
(Browser: Firefox Dev)

```js
var matrix = new DOMMatrix();
matrix.translateSelf(50,50);
console.log("After translate: ", matrix);
matrix.scaleSelf(5); // <-- THIS IS THE PROBLEM!
console.log("After scale: ", matrix);
```

Comment: I don't get those results in Firefox 72.0.1.

Comment: @Pointy Weird. it works in Chrome too. I'm going to close this...